# Air Android ANE - USB manifest

Tags: actionscript-3, android-intent, air, usb, ane

I have made a native Android app with `Eclipse` which controls a RFID USB scanner.
These permissions are requested through the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `intent-filter` and `xml device filter` tag. When I plug the usb device in the Android (`minix`), the permissions are given once and the scanner works perfectly.

Example of the manifest (in the native Android app):

```
<application  
        android:allowBackup="true"  
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
        android:label="@string/app_name"  
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
        <activity  
            android:name=".Main1Activity"  
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main1"  
            android:launchMode="singleTask"  
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
            </intent-filter>  
            <intent-filter>  
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />  
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />  
            </intent-filter>  
            <meta-data  
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"  
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />  
            <meta-data  
                android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"  
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />  
        </activity>  
    </application>
```

The problem is when I build the `ANE` and use this in an `AIR Android` app, these USB permissions are not requested and I don't have access to the device.
What should I place in the AIR Android manifest to access the USB device? I cannot use the intent-filters and meta-data because I don't have access to the XML.

Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: In your AIR application.xml, there should be a node called `android` with a child node called `manifestAdditions`. Can you try adding the intent-filters and metadata there?